# How ro refresh/sync a gradle project in VisualStudioCode

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I have a gradle project imported into VSCode. I'm new to both gradle and vscode.  When I initially imported my project, I didn't have any compilation errors, and it was building just fine.  Now, after running `gradlew clean`, I have red squiggly lines everywhere (even on the Java `String` keyword).

How do I fix this? I'm looking for the gradle equivalent of `mvn install` basically, or a way to sync my gradle, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To sync and refresh you `gradle` dependencies from VSCode.

```
cd android
./gradlew --refresh-dependencies
```

Chill Pill :)

Comment: Does that work? Cos i trying doing this in VSCode terminal, and I got this error  "Task 'refresh-dependencies' not found in root project 'workspace'." In addition, is there any vscode command or button that i can click and run, rather than having to manually type and run the gradlew command.

Comment: please make sure you are in android folder

Comment: run just this  ./gradlew

Comment: I think you mean:
`./gradlew --refresh-dependencies`

Comment: @CortexCompiler yes i think :)

Answer (score 7):

To sync gradle in VSCode.

1. First open the terminal or cmd from the project folder.
2. Then goto the android folder.
3. Call the **gradlew** script.

**For Ubuntu**

```
cd android
./gradlew
```

Answer (score 4):

The command `sh gradlew build` did the trick for me.